# Angular UI Bootstrap just does nothing (no error, not working)

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I`m trying to use Angular UI Bootstrap:

I did the following:

- Install it with bower: `bower install angular-bootstrap`
- Include it in js: `var myapp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.bootstrap' ]);`
- Add styles: `.nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a { cursor: pointer; }`

Bootstrap 3 CSS is included, `angular.element.fn.jquery` returns "2.1.4", so it should not use jqlite.

When I add e.g.:

```
<a href="#" tooltip-placement="left" uib-tooltip="On the Left!">Whatever</a>
```

To my template, nothing happens. When I add other bootstrap ui examples, it also does not do anything.
There are no javascript errors.
My angular.js version is 1.4.1.

What more could I have done wrong? Do I have to do something with my controller?

Comment: can you make [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) of your code ?

Comment: Not really: It`s a complex app. I copied the angular ui bootstrap related things to a plunker, and it worked.
Is there something I can check or debug to see whats going wrong in my app?

Comment: It works now. Solution: Uninstall it with bower, and install it with bower again. Strange. Maybe wiredp or something else in my environment got something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure you are using the last version of ui-bootstrap.
I'm adding this answer as a quick reference for anyone having this problem:

The tooltip attribute (directive) changed from `tooltip` in ui-bootstrap 0.13.X to `uib-tooltip` from version 0.14.0 and up.

If for some reason you can't use the latest version (currently 1.2.X) use the `tooltip` directive and always check the docs for your version of ui-bootstrap at:

[ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Tried hundreds of time with the current Doc.. until I found this answer that made me realise I should have checked the version first. +1 mate!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the bower package (if that's what you're using) is

> angular-bootstrap

and nothing else; there's a similar one that's wrong.

Looking at their own example page this is the order to include the scripts for angular and ui-bootstrap:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="lib/bootswatch/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom stylesheet -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then check for JS errors in the web browser console (I use Chrome).